# Postman not getting response from POST

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express

Using Express/Node and Postgres ('pg' package).

Code:

```
const createEvent = (request, response) => {

    console.log(request.body);
    const {
        type,
        location,
        current_attendees,
        total_attendees,
        details,
        event_date,
        has_car,
        has_food,
        cover_charge,
        contact_email,
    } = request.body;

    pool.query(`INSERT INTO events (type, location, current_attendees, total_attendees, details, event_date, has_car, has_food, cover_charge, contact_email) VALUES ('${type}', '${location}', ${current_attendees}, ${total_attendees}, '${details}', TO_DATE('${event_date}', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), ${has_car}, ${has_food}, ${cover_charge}, '${contact_email}')`),
                (error, results) => {
                    if (error) {
                        throw error;
                    }
                    console.log(results);
                    response.status(201).send('Event created');                    
                }
}
```

Route:

```
router.post('/events', db.createEvent);
```

The object gets inserted into the database just fine and I get the request body's console log, but I don't get the results console log and no response is sent back to postman. It just times out.

I'm sending a normal JSON object (Body -> Raw -> Text -> JSON).

[image: postman screenshot]

Any idea what's going on? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short - when your code runs it get's to `pool.query(...)` line (which is async function) and it does not wait for the response, because you haven't specified that you want to wait for it.
Solution would be to make createEvent function async:

`const createEvent = async (request, response)`

and wait for DB response:

`await pool.query(...)`

Read more about [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) and/or [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Answer (score 0):

I see that the url it's http:localhost:8080/api/events you added the /api to the route, or is a sub router in express